# Typescript: cannot cast down to generic "Record<string, string>" type?

Tags: typescript

Why won't typescript allow me to cast the following:

```
interface foo {
  foofoo: string
  feefee: string
  faafaa: 'red' | 'blue'
}
```

into `Record<string, string>` ? How do I make that happen?

I've tried:

- changing the string literals red|blue to just `string` type
- tried `instanceOfFoo as Record<string, string>`
- tried changing it into a type instead of an interface

...no joy whatsoever any help appreciated

Comment: That has three strings, you want a Record with two strings.

Comment: That's not a valid interface declaration, the `=` is only used in a type alias... which actually works with this assignment.

Comment: Sorry bout the typo... i was switching between type and interface trying diff things. will correct questions @a

Comment: Well it should work with a type alias: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300 -- post your actual code and error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript signals an error here not because the two types are not assignable to one another, but because *they have no properties in common*, this is almost always made by mistake, and the instruction on the error is fairly clear on what to do in the case that is not.

> Conversion of type 'foo' to type 'Record' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, **convert the expression to 'unknown' first**.

Emphasis mine.

So what you need to do is something like

```
declare const x: foo; // there exists a variable x of type foo.
const y = x as unknown as Record<string, string>; // cast to unknown, then to Record.
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyAzmFKAOYDc+hARnFGQOTHrvIA+y7FlHYMAvrlwATCAgA2rFAnQhKyAB5kM6BriUqwyAJ7IAvOuRxyyAEoz0USQB5K1EDQA0FKrQB8dZAD0AciYAA7kusqqAF6m5pbIAK4gANYg6ADuIBZWtkoOzt5uni6+-kHIGfYp5EA)

Comment: That was my exact error message, and your solution worked! Thank you! I resisted casting to unknown because I had gotten used to the linter complaining about "any" types and confused the two...

Comment: Or you can just use a type alias instead of an interface.

Comment: @AaronBeall the project's linter didn't let me, but who knows... it might have been because I had done something else wrong. I feel like ur 100% right tho! thx for the info. Super new to typescript.